# "And" and "Or" troubles within an IF statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use "And" & "Or" within an If statement. I probably have my syntax wrong.

the result comes back false when the data should make it true. Here is the code:

```
ElseIf (origNum = "006260006" Or origNum = "30062600006") And creditOrDebit = "D" Then

'do things here

End If
```

-When I debug and come to this line it hops over it and doesn't enter in.

-origNum actually equals "006260006" and creditOrDebit = "D".

-so I'm assuming my "Or" statement isn't working.

-Hopefully this is a quick easy question. Thanks!

Comment: Type issue maybe?  Are you dealing with the numbers as numbers or strings?  did you not declare them as either?

Comment: Your code works for me... Are you sure `origNum` is not of a numerical type? Are you sure the `If` has not executed?

Comment: Same question as these guys, should `origNum = "006260006"` really not be `origNum = 006260006`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is probably somewhere else. Try this code for example:

```
Sub test()

  origNum = "006260006"
  creditOrDebit = "D"

  If (origNum = "006260006" Or origNum = "30062600006") And creditOrDebit = "D" Then
    MsgBox "OK"
  End If

End Sub
```

And you will see that your `Or` works as expected. Are you sure that your `ElseIf` statement is executed (it will not be executed if any of the if/elseif before is true)?

Comment: I found the problem.
**The ACTUAL problem:**

-for some reason, in the cells where origNum picked up the number, a bunch of cells had a space in front of the numbers so origNumb ACTUALLY contained " 006260006" instead of "006260006"

-to Solve this problem I used Trim() on any data that was stored in the variables

Comment: The Solution:

I changed my code back to:

ElseIf (origNum = "006260006" Or origNum = "30062600006") And creditOrDebit = "D" Then

'do things here

End If

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer the question..My reputation is too low lol.

Comment: @MikeKellogg It's a good question so I upvoted, hopefully others will as well. You should see your rep increase.

Comment: Thanks JP! I can answer my own questions now :D

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment.

In reply to [JP's answers / comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123972/829571), I have run the following test to compare the performance of the 2 methods. The `Profiler` object is a custom class - but in summary, it uses a kernel32 function which is fairly accurate (`Private Declare Sub GetLocalTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)`).

```
Sub test()

  Dim origNum As String
  Dim creditOrDebit As String
  Dim b As Boolean
  Dim p As Profiler
  Dim i As Long

  Set p = New_Profiler

  origNum = "30062600006"
  creditOrDebit = "D"

  p.startTimer ("nested_ifs")

  For i = 1 To 1000000

    If creditOrDebit = "D" Then
      If origNum = "006260006" Then
        b = True
      ElseIf origNum = "30062600006" Then
        b = True
      End If
    End If

  Next i

  p.stopTimer ("nested_ifs")
  p.startTimer ("or_and")

  For i = 1 To 1000000

    If (origNum = "006260006" Or origNum = "30062600006") And creditOrDebit = "D" Then
      b = True
    End If

  Next i

  p.stopTimer ("or_and")

  p.printReport

End Sub
```

The results of 5 runs (in ms for 1m loops):

> 20-Jun-2012 19:28:25
>   nested_ifs (x1): 156 - Last Run: 156 - Average Run: 156
>   or_and (x1): 125 - Last Run: 125 - Average Run: 125
>
> 20-Jun-2012 19:28:26
>   nested_ifs (x1): 156 - Last Run: 156 - Average Run: 156
>   or_and (x1): 125 - Last Run: 125 - Average Run: 125
>
> 20-Jun-2012 19:28:27
>   nested_ifs (x1): 140 - Last Run: 140 - Average Run: 140
>   or_and (x1): 125 - Last Run: 125 - Average Run: 125
>
> 20-Jun-2012 19:28:28
>   nested_ifs (x1): 140 - Last Run: 140 - Average Run: 140
>   or_and (x1): 141 - Last Run: 141 - Average Run: 141
>
> 20-Jun-2012 19:28:29
>   nested_ifs (x1): 156 - Last Run: 156 - Average Run: 156
>   or_and (x1): 125 - Last Run: 125 - Average Run: 125

**Note**

If `creditOrDebit` is not `"D"`, JP's code runs faster (around 60ms vs. 125ms for the or/and code).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I did some tests as well, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123287/190829)' answer, however I would refactor it as follows:

```
Sub test()

Dim origNum As String
Dim creditOrDebit As String

origNum = "30062600006"
creditOrDebit = "D"

If creditOrDebit = "D" Then
  If origNum = "006260006" Then
    MsgBox "OK"
  ElseIf origNum = "30062600006" Then
    MsgBox "OK"
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

This might save you some CPU cycles since if `creditOrDebit` is `<> "D"` there is no point in checking the value of `origNum`.

### Update:

I used the following procedure to test my theory that my procedure is faster:

```
Public Declare Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long

Sub DoTests2()

  Dim startTime1 As Long
  Dim endTime1 As Long
  Dim startTime2 As Long
  Dim endTime2 As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim msg As String

  Const numberOfLoops As Long = 10000
  Const origNum As String = "006260006"
  Const creditOrDebit As String = "D"

  startTime1 = timeGetTime
  For i = 1 To numberOfLoops
    If creditOrDebit = "D" Then
      If origNum = "006260006" Then
        ' do something here
        Debug.Print "OK"
      ElseIf origNum = "30062600006" Then
        ' do something here
        Debug.Print "OK"
      End If
    End If
  Next i
  endTime1 = timeGetTime

  startTime2 = timeGetTime
  For i = 1 To numberOfLoops
    If (origNum = "006260006" Or origNum = "30062600006") And _
      creditOrDebit = "D" Then
      ' do something here
      Debug.Print "OK"
    End If
  Next i
  endTime2 = timeGetTime

  msg = "number of iterations: " & numberOfLoops & vbNewLine
  msg = msg & "JP proc: " & Format$((endTime1 - startTime1), "#,###") & _
       " ms" & vbNewLine
  msg = msg & "assylias proc: " & Format$((endTime2 - startTime2), "#,###") & _
       " ms"

  MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

I must have a slow computer because 1,000,000 iterations took nowhere near ~200 ms as with [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125916/190829)' test. I had to limit the iterations to 10,000 -- hey, I have other things to do :)

After running the above procedure 10 times, my procedure is faster only 20% of the time. However, when it is slower it is only superficially slower. As [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125916/190829) pointed out, however, when `creditOrDebit` is `<>"D"`, my procedure is at least twice as fast. I was able to reasonably test it at 100 million iterations.

And *that* is why I refactored it - to short-circuit the logic so that `origNum` doesn't need to be evaluated when `creditOrDebit <> "D"`.

At this point, the rest depends on the OP's spreadsheet. If `creditOrDebit` is likely to equal D, then use [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125916/190829)' procedure, because it will usually run faster. But if `creditOrDebit` has a wide range of possible values, and `D` is not any more likely to be the target value, my procedure will leverage that to prevent needlessly evaluating the other variable.

Comment: how does this actually save cycles, since the OP's and @assylias answer will evaluate both origNum and creditOrDebit? Does it really take that much longer to evaluate a joined If statement versus blocking it out. I do think that yours is ultimately easier to read though.

Comment: 1. readability sould be the priority over CPU cycles. 2. a quick test shows that your solution is slightly slower (depending on the run). 3. The performance difference is in the region of 25 nanoseconds, so unlikely to be a bottleneck (and if it is, vba is clearly not an option!)

Comment: @Scott `the OP's and @assylias answer will evaluate both origNum and creditOrDebit` yes, in one line both will be evaluated, whereas in mine, only one will be evaluated. Only if `creditOrDebit = "D"` is true will it evaluate `origNum`.

Comment: @assylias Can you update your answer with the metric you are using?

Comment: @Scott FYI, see my new answer

Comment: this is really intersting stuff, I'm glad I generated so much conversation :)